# Comparing dates hiberanate criteria queries

Tags: hibernate, date, criteria, equality

I have following ceode to campare all fields of "Creative" class. some fields are dates.

```
Criteria creativeCriteria = getSession().createCriteria(PcmCreative.class);
    for(Entry<String,Object> mapEntry : propValMap.entrySet()){
        if(mapEntry.getValue() == null){
            creativeCriteria.add(Restrictions.isNull(mapEntry.getKey()));
            //creativeCriteria.add(Restrictions.disjunction().add(Restrictions.isNull(mapEntry.getKey())).add(Restrictions.eq(mapEntry.getKey(),mapEntry.getValue())));
        }else{
            creativeCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq(mapEntry.getKey(),mapEntry.getValue()));
        }
    }
    creativeCriteria.createAlias("campaign", "c").add(Restrictions.eq("c.campaignNumber", campaignNumber));
    creativeCriteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount());
    return (Integer)creativeCriteria.uniqueResult();
```

I format my dates using follwing code :

```
   String strDate = DateUtils.convertDateToString((Date)     fieldValue,CmtConstants.CMTDATE_MYSQL_COMPARISION_FORMAT);
//fieldValue = DateUtils.convertStringToDate(strDate,CmtConstants.CMTDATE_MYSQL_COMPARISION_FORMAT);
```

where CMTDATE_MYSQL_COMPARISION_FORMAT is 'yyyy-mm-dd'.

but comparision fails. as date returned by DateUtils.convertStringToDate, which internally uses SimpleDateFormat.parse method,contains GMT string as well which I think fails critrai equality in hibernate. Any soulutions how to remove GMT string and get dates only containing date and time parts?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write utility to convert the date format before adding it is criteria as below.

```
 private java.sql.Date getSQLDate(Object dateObj) {

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = null;
    try {

        sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
        java.util.Date utilDate = sdf.parse((String) dateObj);
        if (utilDate == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
        }

    } catch (ParseException parseEx) {
       }

}
```